# Configure table of contents, figures, tables for classicthesis

Tags: table-of-contents, classicthesis

Hello i'm not so experienced on Latex and have one question .I am trying to configure table of contents, list of figures,list of tables since all of them appear automatically using:

```
% book example for classicthesis.sty
\documentclass[
% Replace twoside with oneside if you are printing your thesis on a single side
% of the paper, or for viewing on screen.
%oneside,
oneside,
11pt, a4paper,
footinclude=true,
headinclude=true,
cleardoublepage=empty
]{scrbook}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[linedheaders,parts,pdfspacing]{classicthesis}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{acronym}
\usepackage[titles]{tocloft}
\usepackage{tocloft}
\usepackage{minitoc}
\usepackage{times}
\usepackage{setspace}
\renewcommand{\contentsname}{TABLE OF CONTENTS}
\renewcommand{\cftchapfont}{\normalfont}
\renewcommand{\cftchappagefont}{\normalfont}
\renewcommand{\cftchapleader}{\cftdotfill{\cftdotsep}}
\renewcommand{\cftpartleader}{\cftdotfill{\cftdotsep}} 
\renewcommand{\listfigurename}{LIST OF FIGURES}
\setlength{\cftbeforefigskip}{0.25in}
\renewcommand{\cftchappagefont}{\normalfont}
\renewcommand{\cftchapleader}{\cftdotfill{\cftdotsep}}

\renewcommand{\listtablename}{LIST OF TABLES}
\setlength{\cftbeforetabskip}{0.2in}

\title{Thesis Title}
\author{John Doe}

\begin{document}

\maketitle
\frontmatter
\tableofcontents
\listoffigures 
\listoftables 

\chapter{Acknowledgements} 

I would like to thank my supervisor, Professor Someone. This 
research was funded by the Imaginary Research Council. 

\chapter{Abstract} 

A brief summary of the project goes here. 

\chapter{Abbreviations}

\mainmatter 

\include{intro2} 

\backmatter  

\begin{thebibliography}{100} % 100 is a random guess of the total number of 
 %references 
\end{thebibliography}

\end{document}
```

and for the intro2.tex:

```
\chapter{Introduction} 
\label{ch:intro} 
\section{Blabal}

blaalblbla
\subsection{blubl} 
blublbu
```

In the table of contents the page of the subsections are still on the left and not on the right with no dots (don't really care about the dots just want them to be aligned on the right) and the same is also happening in the pages on list of figures and tables. I hope someone can trace the problem. Thanks in advance.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: At first glance (without MWE) I would say, most of your `\renewcommand{}` aren't necessary at all.

Comment: whether or not dots are shown connecting title and page number depends on the document class you are using.  without that information, we can't help you.  best to follow the request by @ChristianHupfer and provide a small compilable example.

Comment: Do you guys know the `classicthesis`-option `dottedtoc`?

Comment: @Johannes_B: Well, consider the time when the comments was written and the time the MWE was added (about 10 hours later!), so we could not know about `classicthesis` at all. You can add another answer as well ;-)

Answer (score 2):

The `classicthesis.sty` has some strange behaviour (in my point of view), it disables dot filling in ToC/LoF,LoT.

Using `tocloft` package, this can be cured via following macros

```
% For ToC

\renewcommand{\cftsecleader}{\cftdotfill{\cftdotsep}}
\renewcommand{\cftsubsecleader}{\cftdotfill{\cftdotsep}}
\renewcommand{\cftsubsubsecleader}{\cftdotfill{\cftdotsep}}

% For LoF/LoT

\renewcommand{\cftfigleader}{\cftdotfill{\cftdotsep}}
\renewcommand{\cfttableader}{\cftdotfill{\cftdotsep}}
```

### main.tex -- driver file

```
% book example for classicthesis.sty
\documentclass[
% Replace twoside with oneside if you are printing your thesis on a single side
% of the paper, or for viewing on screen.
%oneside,
oneside,
11pt, a4paper,
footinclude=true,
headinclude=true,
cleardoublepage=empty
]{scrbook}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[linedheaders,parts,pdfspacing]{classicthesis}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{acronym}
\usepackage[titles]{tocloft}
\usepackage{minitoc}
%\usepackage{times}% Deprecated -- use mathptmx instead
\usepackage{mathptmx}%
\usepackage{setspace}
\renewcommand{\contentsname}{TABLE OF CONTENTS}%
\renewcommand{\listfigurename}{LIST OF FIGURES}%
\renewcommand{\cftchapfont}{\normalfont}

\setlength{\cftbeforefigskip}{0.25in}
\renewcommand{\cftchappagefont}{\normalfont}
\renewcommand{\cftchapleader}{\cftdotfill{\cftdotsep}}

% My additions 09/13/2014
\renewcommand{\cftsecleader}{\cftdotfill{\cftdotsep}}
\renewcommand{\cftsubsecleader}{\cftdotfill{\cftdotsep}}
\renewcommand{\cftsubsubsecleader}{\cftdotfill{\cftdotsep}}
\renewcommand{\cftfigleader}{\cftdotfill{\cftdotsep}}
\renewcommand{\cfttableader}{\cftdotfill{\cftdotsep}}


\renewcommand{\listtablename}{LIST OF TABLES}
\setlength{\cftbeforetabskip}{0.2in}

\title{Thesis Title}
\author{John Doe}

 \begin{document}

\maketitle
\frontmatter
\tableofcontents
\listoffigures 
\listoftables 

\chapter{Acknowledgements} 

I would like to thank my supervisor, Professor Someone. This 
research was funded by the Imaginary Research Council. 

\chapter{Abstract} 

A brief summary of the project goes here. 

\chapter{Abbreviations}

\mainmatter 

\include{intro2} 

\backmatter  

\begin{thebibliography}{100} % 100 is a random guess of the total number of 
  % references 
\end{thebibliography}

\end{document}
```

### intro2.tex

```
\chapter{Introduction} 
\label{ch:intro} 
\section{Blabal}

blaalblbla
\subsection{blubl} 
blublbu

\begin{figure}
  \caption{This is a dummy figure}
\end{figure}

\begin{table}
  \begin{center}
    \begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|c|}
      \hline
      & & & & \tabularnewline
      This & is & a & small & table \tabularnewline
      & & & & \tabularnewline
      \hline
    \end{tabular}
    \caption{This is a dummy table}
  \end{center}
\end{table}
```

In `intro2.tex` I added a dummy figure as well as a dummy table to show the effects on the LoF/LoT too.

[image]

Comment: [Configure table of contents, figures, tables for classicthesis](http://tex.stackexchange.com/posts/comments/467640)

Comment: The reason is by no means mysterious: Bringhurst has the opinion that the page numbers in a table of contents are not to be summed up, so it's really unnecessary to line them up. There's no real reason for filling up a page with dots either.